# how to make <iframe> height and width automatically changable, when the content of iframe dynamically changed?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a widget, which have a popup elements ( datepicker ), and when datepicker is shown, it can't fit into fixed size of iframe.

Comment: The short-answer is you can't. The contents of the iframe are independent of the page which is serving the iframe, though with ajax / passing url params to the src-attribute of the iframe you might be able to work something out... So maybe pass a url-param to the iframe & if you're controlling the page shown in the iframe, add some logic to the datepicker if the url-param is present (a $_GET variable passedto the iframe, is <iframe src="someurl/?is_shown='true>)

Answer (score 0):

The size of a parent element does not change based on the size of the child elements, usually. What you can do, however, is set the width and height of the iframe to percentages, which will change based on the parent size.

```css
body {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 768px;
}

.frame {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://stackoverflow.com/" class="frame" />
```